# Set a default named range for Excel worksheet

Tags: excel

I'm trying to save a spreadsheet and have users be able to enter data in a specific cell order and I've gotten as far as saving the named range.

Is there any way to set it default so the user starts on cell 1 and each time they hit enter it follows the range? Right now they have to click in the first cell and select the name from the drop down and it'd be preferred if they didn't have to do that every time.

Edit: Doesn't look like it's possible without VBA code, named ranges can't hold the number of cells that I need to go through. How would I approach this?

Comment: @pnuts If it can be done without VBA code that would be ideal, if it can only be done that way then it's no big deal.

Comment: I think if you protect the sheet, you can disable selection of locked cells, so Tab and Enter would move only to the unlocked cells

Comment: I agree with @Slai. That is the best solution without VBA. The unlocked cells should be in sequence though.